# Qt QMainWindow bar below hiding widgets

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating an application using Qt and the main window (QMainWindow) had something I don't want but I am not sure how to remove it. Tried to remove statusbar but it seems like the bar below still exist. See the image below.

[main window bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2f7R.png)

Anyone please let me know how to remove the bar as shown in the image.

Comment: Could you please provide some code?

Comment: I've removed the statusbar through Qt Designer, not much code related, I just wonder what bar is that, and how should that bar be remove.

Comment: what code are you using to remove the bar?

Comment: The bar was removed using Qt Designer, well, I know what was it anyway, it was the centralwidget having different width/height that causes this..

Comment: I know that you removed it using the designer, but what code were your trying to use?